# Stopping ansible from a playbook (site.yml)

Tags: ansible

I have re-written the question to be more specific instead of using a generic example of what I am trying to achieve, as per @Zeitounator's suggestion.

I use ansible to spin up VM's in VMware by adding a new entry in the `hosts.ini` file and running `ansible-playbook -i inventory/dev/hosts.ini --limit SomeGroup playbooks/site.yml`

The vmware role (called`vmware`) will
* check to see if the VM already exists. 
* If it does, then obviously it does not create the VM.
* If it does not exist, then it will create the VM from a template.

To destroy a VM, I run this: `ansible-playbook -i inventory/dev/hosts.ini --limit SomeGroup playbooks/site.yml -e 'vmware_destroy=true'`

That works as intended. Now for my issue.

When this variable is set (`vmware_destroy=true`), it will destroy the VM successfully, BUT ansible will attempt to carry on with the rest of the playbook on the host that has just been destroyed. Obviously it fails. The playbook does actually stop due to the failure. But not gracefully.

Here is an example of the flow of logic:

```
$ cat playbooks/site.yml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - { role: vmware, tags: vmware }

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
  - { role: bootstrap, tags: bootstrap }
  - { role: common, tags: common }

- hosts: AppServers
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - { role: application }
# and so on.
```

```
$ cat playbooks/roles/vmware/main.yml
---
# Checks to see if the VM exists already.
# A variable `found_vm` is registered in this task.
- import_tasks: find.yml

# Only import this task when all of the `when` conditions are met.
- import_tasks: destroy.yml
  when:
    - vmware_destroy is defined
    - vmware_destroy # Meaning 'True'
    - found_vm

# If the above is true, it will not import this task.
- import_tasks: create.yml
  when:
    - found_vm.failed
    - vmware_destroy is not defined
```

So, the point is, when I specify `-e 'vmware_destroy=true'`, ansible will attempt to run the rest of the playbook and fail.

I don't want ansible to fail. I want it to stop gracefully after completing the `vmware` role based on `-e 'vmware_destroy=true` flag provided on the command line.

I am aware I can use a different playbook for this, something like:
`ansible-playbook -i inventory/dev/hosts.ini --limit SomeGroup playbooks/VMWARE_DESTROY.yml`. But I would rather use a variable as opposed to a separate playbook. If there is a strong argument to split out the playbook in this way, please provide references.

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear what I want to do. Stop the playbook before it reaches the end. I will clarify this even further.

Comment: `meta: end_play` ends a play, as its name suggests, not a playbook. Since there are no conditions to stop after first play, simply remove the other plays you don't want to run from your file (KISS principle)... or try to better explain the root of what you are trying to achieve exactly because you might not be on the good track.

Answer (score 0):

A playbook is the top Ansible abstraction layer (playbook -> role -> task -> ...). There are 2 more layers in [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx)  (workflow -> job template -> playbook ...) to control the playbooks. To follow the architecture either AWX, or any other tool to interface Ansible ([ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner), or scripts for example) should be used to control the playbooks.

Controlling of the playbooks inside Ansible is rather awkward. Create 2 playbooks *vmware-create.yml* and *vmware-destroy.yml*

```
$ cat vmware-create.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes  # include cached variables
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: Don't create VM this time. End of play.
        - meta: end_play
      when: not hostvars['localhost'].vmware_create
    - debug:
        msg: Create VM.

$ cat vmware-destroy.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes  # include cached variables
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: Don't destroy VM this time. End of play.
        - meta: end_play
      when: not hostvars['localhost'].vmware_destroy
    - debug:
        msg: Destroy VM.
```

and import them into the playbook *vmware_control.yml*. See below

```
$ cat vmware-control.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vmware_create: true
    vmware_destroy: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
       vmware_create: "{{ vmware_create }}"     # cache variable
    - set_fact:
        vmware_destroy: "{{ vmware_destroy }}"  # cache variable

- import_playbook: vmware-create.yml
- import_playbook: vmware-destroy.yml
```

Control the flow with the variables *vmware_create* and *vmware_destroy*. Run *vmware_control.yml* at *localhost* and declare *hosts: all* inside *vmware-create.yml* and *vmware-destroy.yml*.

Comment: From https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html:
"end_play (added in Ansible 2.2) causes the play to end without failing the host(s). Note that this affects all hosts."
So it ends the play, but not the playbook.

Comment: @Vladimir, Thank you for taking the time to write an answer for the question. I have rewritten the question to be more specific rather than generic. Cheers.

Comment: I can only assume you have not tried the conditional import. It won't work. `ERROR! this task 'import_playbook' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: shell, win_shell, include_vars, add_host, raw, include_role, meta, set_fact, include, import_tasks, script, import_role, include_tasks, group_by, command, win_command`
Conditional import of a playbook is a current feature request. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34281#issuecomment-479013767
Any other suggestions on the www? I have yet to find a workable solution that doesn't create unnecessary clutter.

Comment: You're right. The conditions shall be inside the playbooks. I've updated the answer.